# Mysql UPDATE ceased working

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-update

Please could somebody supply some fresh eyes, this simple script was working faultlessly yesterday morning (before I started to jockey about with it) in my test environment.

I created a new identical page which also gave an admin the ability to alter 2 further fields but all I was getting was a blank page when the script ran, I even copied the working examples to the other files and it still wouldn't process which seemed really weird, now for some reason this one won't process either.

If somebody could point me in the direction of the piece of the jigsaw I've deleted I'd be very grateful

The Form:

```
<form action="scripts/editdata.php" method="post" name="pEdit">                                                                                                                              
<div><input type="hidden" name="editId" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"></div>
<div id="uploadDate" class="fluid"><input class="red" type="text"   name="editDate" value="<?php echo $livedate; ?>" /></div>
<div id="uploadUrl" class="fluid"><input class="red" type="url" name="editUrl" value="<?php echo $url; ?>" /></div>
<div id="uploadAddress" class="fluid red"><input class="red" type="text" name="editAddress" value="<?php echo $address; ?>" /></div>
<div id="uploadTown" class="fluid"><input class="red" type="text" name="editTown" value="<?php echo $town; ?>" /></div>
<div id="uploadLatitude" class="fluid"><input class="red" type="text" name="editLatitude" value="<?php echo $latitude; ?>" /></div>
<div id="uploadLongitude" class="fluid"><input class="red" type="text" name="editLongitude" value="<?php echo $longitude; ?> " /></div> 
<div id="uploadBtn" class="fluid"><input type="submit" name="uploadBtn" value="Update Property" />
</form></div>
```

The Query (editdata.php):

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE enabled_boards SET live_date=?, url=?, address=?, town=?, latitude=?, longitude=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $_POST['editDate'], $_POST['editUrl'], $_POST['editAddress'], $_POST['editTown'], $_POST['editLatitude'],   $_POST['editLongitude'], $_POST['editId']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: can you tell me exact what error you got?

Comment: Hi Raja, when I first created the script I had problems and added affected_rows which indicated -1

Comment: Sorry I hit enter, then the problem stopped and the script worked perfectly from then on, it was when I tried to duplicate the page in another filename it wouldn't work again yet the other one still worked fine, i tried exact copies with different filenames still it would't process. Now neither work, I've also tried deleting all fields and just updating the 1 and still the query fails, I've also tried other ways that I have searched on here and nothing seems to work. Thanks for your help raja

Comment: you are mixing mysqli and PDO use one of them either mysqli or PDO then check it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

> I think you marge up mysqli and php pdo. Either use mysqli or pdo
>   don't merge up both in one.

I am showing you the example with pdo.

Read manual [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname, $username, $password");
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE enabled_boards SET live_date=?, url=?, address=?, town=?, latitude=?, longitude=? WHERE id=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssssi", $_POST['editDate'], $_POST['editUrl'], $_POST['editAddress'], $_POST['editTown'], $_POST['editLatitude'],   $_POST['editLongitude'], $_POST['editId']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Hi Saty, I've not discovered PDO yet, I'm just getting to grips with mysqli, I've just put your code on the page and the same thing happens it simply opens editdata.php, I'm guessing because the script is perhaps "stuck"? it should  simply load the html elements for 2 secs then redirect back to the admin page .

Comment: You are redirecting the form on the same page?

Comment: No the form is located at "editform.php", the forms action is "editdata.php" which if successfully processed displays the html on it for 2 seconds before going back to the admin page where another selection can be made of another record to edit.

Comment: okk check print_r($_POST); die(); in your editform.php at top inside php tag and check what it show

Comment: I tried that code Saty and I still have a blank screen, as I have clearly mixed up mysqli and PDO I've just changed it to the following and I still have a blank screen, no success message or errors

Comment: `$id = 'editId';
    $date = 'editDate';
    $url = 'editUrl';
    $address = 'editAddress';
    $town = 'editTown';
    $latitude = 'editLatitude';
    $longitude = 'editLongitude';

    $query = "UPDATE enabled_boards SET live_date=?, url=?, address=?, town=?, latitude=?, longitude=? WHERE id=?";
    $statement = $mysqli->prepare($query);

    $results = $statement->bind_param('ssssssi', $date, $web, $address,     $locality, $lat, $long, $id);

    if($results){
        print 'Success! record updated'; 
    }else{
        print 'Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error;
    }`

Comment: use only mysqli or pdo don't merge up both

Comment: Is that not mysqli ? I'm now really confused

Comment: Right I think I've made a little headway, I've tried the PDO code again that you 1st gave me and I have managed to get an output from print_r($_POST); everything is as I would expect except this: [uploadBtn] => Update Property which is appended to the Array, that is the name of the button and the value, how is that getting into the query?